# Passing HashMap using intent returns null, why?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, hashmap

I'm trying to pass a hashmap from one activity to another using intent. I already found a solution which should work. I implemented `Serializable` in class Player.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Player> players = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();
players.put(1, new Player("name"));
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("players", players);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I want to get the hashmap in the other activivity it returns null.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
players = (HashMap<Integer, Player>) intent.getSerializableExtra("player");
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions? I just can't find my mistake.

Comment: Is your Player Class Implements serializable... ???

Comment: `"player"` or `"players"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a typo here:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
players = (HashMap<Integer, Player>) intent.getSerializableExtra("player");
```

Did you mean:

```
getSerializableExtra("players");
```